# Is it possible to access Google Account Settings from a 3rd party application?

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have recently found out an application (I won't name it, but it's a personal security solution) that can read my Google Account settings in order to give recommendations (e.g: enable 2FA, manage connected devices etc).

I have researched this area before and I didn't find any way to actually obtain these settings. Therefore, I am wondering what I'm missing.

In the application you're prompted to login to your address in a in-app browser. After you've logged in, the mentioned data is obtained. No Connected App appears in the settings of the Google Account, just another session from my mobile device with the label of IOS Account Manager (my phone is indeed an apple device).

I'm just wondering, how could they read this data then? Is it likely that they use a in-app browser and just parse the contents of the pages after you login? Would this be a legitimate use? Have I missed any API that google has?

**Seeing a close vote already I've decided to rephrase with the hope that the question is understood:**
Is there a legitimate way to access, for example, the settings of a Google Account, such as an API?

Comment: You might have to start by getting familiar with https://developers.google.com and https://cloud.google.com

Comment: @Rubén "I have researched this area before and I didn't find any way to actually obtain these settings. Therefore, I am wondering what I'm missing." - this should be explicit enough. I haven't found a way to access the settings in any of Google API's (excluding Workspace). If you know sometimes, could you please leave a link to the documentation?